# How to assign / change the Access Points SSID programatically

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi

Using a Rpi 3A (B or B+) with Buster. Its set up as an access point with an SSID of WaiterControl, a static IP address, and I have Mosquitto on it to control MQTT messages.  I have various ESP32 modules that connect to this for controlling several items.

What I'd like to do is have three jumpers on the hat that connect to the Rpi's IO.  I'd like to use these jumpers to change / assign the SSID for this particular Rpi,  i.e.  if no jumpers,  SSID would be WaiterControl.  If one jumper, SSID would be WaiterControl1.  Two jumpers would be WaiterControl2,  etc, etc.

The ESP32s would also have jumpers so they could match the SSID of the Rpi that they are supposed to talk to.

Why do I want to do this?  I hard coded the wifi stuff so there is zero configuration by the installer or user;  just plug it in and it works.  I've also found the wifi to be very robust, if it losses a connection it reconnects with no problems.  However,  its theoretically possible (very, very remote possibility) that I could have twp Rpis in close proximity and their networks (the Rpi and corresponding ESP32s) could get confused and talk to the wrong Rpi.  By allowing some type of network SSID assignments I could eliminate this possibility.

Comment: Refer this discussion https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=201002
and
this tutorial https://github.com/SurferTim/documentation/blob/master/configuration/wireless/access-point.md